# select won't show default value when list is read from server angularjs

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, html-select, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have this below select which won't show the default value when statuslist is read from the server through a http call in IE9. If statuslist values are set in the controller itself then default value show up fine.

```
<select id="status" class="form-control" ng-init="selectedStatus = statuslist[0]"
                            ng-model="selectedStatus"
                            ng-options="status for status in statuslist">
                    </select>
```

Default value is displayed in the dropdown if I do this

```
 $scope.statuslist = [
            "New",
            "Management Review"
        ]
```

but not if the statuslist is from the server. I can see the list if I click the dropdown but not the default value.

Can someone please point at the obvious I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-init` shouldn't be used there, because it will get evaluated as the html get rendered and at that time `statuslist` value was not getting loaded inside `$scope`, so it will set as `selectedStatus` as `undefined`

Better you should add this line `$scope.selectedStatus = $scope.statuslist[0]` right after after the `statuslist` gets loaded from the server.

Comment: Thanks. That's quick. I will select this answer when I am able to.

Comment: @yalkris Glad to here that it does helped..Thanks :)